# Cross Platform Custom File Header in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, qt, file, cross-platform

I'm currently working on a project that encrypts files and adds them to the application's library. I need to version the file format so that I'm planning to prepend a file header to the encrypted file. The project is in Qt and currently for Windows. Later will make app for android and mac as well.

FOr this I made these structures, the version 1 file.

```
struct Header_Meta
{
    char signature [4];
    char version [4];
};

struct Header_v1
{
    char id [12];
    char flag [8];
    char name [128];
    long size;
};

union File_v1
{
    Header_Meta meta;
    Header_v1 header;
    byte null [512 - sizeof (Header_Meta) - sizeof (Header_v1)];
    byte data [MAX_HEADERv1];
};
```

The file is binary file.
Now in the getDetails() function, I'll read the MAX_HEADERv1 bytes to file_v1.data and will get the details in the member variables.

My questions are

1. Is there a better approach?
2. Is there any problem writing the long size of Header_v1 to file, in cases of platform differences?
3. The logic should work the same way in all devices with file from another platform. Will this hold?

Comment: Will there be datatype size issues on different platforms? Since you are writing long value to file...

Comment: You also must care about endianness.

Comment: Don't forget about fields alignment (`#pragma pack`). Don't forget about byte ordering.

Comment: Fields alignment? What's it?

Comment: Are you sure you mean to use a `union` for your `File_v1` data type? All the members will be stored in the same memory location.

Comment: I used it just to read the whole number of bytes to the variable. Otherwise I will use the address of the variable for this. Not big deal :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a slight possibility that you will end up having a lot of `#ifdef BIG/LITTLE_ENDIAN`'s in the code depending on the platform you are trying to deploy your product. I would use for the `long size` to be like: `unsigned char size[8]` (this would yield a 64 (=8*8) bit value) and then you could use a formula in your code, like:

```
uint64_t real_size = size[0] + size[1] << 8 + size[2] << 16 + ....
```

and when calculating individual `size` bytes you could do it like:

```
size[0] = real_size && 0xFF;
size[1] = (real_size && 0xFF00) >> 8;
size[2] = (real_size && 0xFF0000) >> 16;
```

and so on...

and from this point on you just need to worry about correctly writing out the bytes of `size` to their corresponding position.

Regarding the version string you want to add to the header (`char version[4]`) it all depends on what do you want to store there. If you want to put textual information (such as: `"v1.0"`) you will limit the possible version you can have, so I would recommend again putting in a binary version, such as:

```
version[0] = VERSION      // customers usually pay for an increase in this
version[1] = RELEASE      // new functionality, it's up to you if customer pays or not :)
version[2] = MAINTENANCE  // planned maintenance, usually customers don't pay for this
version[3] = PATCH        // emergency patch, hopefully you never have to use this
```

This will allow for version numbers in the form of `VERSION.RELEASE.MAINTENACE.PATCH` and you can go up to 255.255.255.255

Also, please pay attention to @Ben's comment, the `union` just feels wrong. Usually these fields should come one after the other, but with the union they all will overlap each other, starting at the same location.

Comment: Is there a better approach for file versioning and adding header?

Comment: It'd be a lot easier to always store the `uint64_t` in the file in network (big-endian) byte order using `htonll()` and always read it using `ntohll()`.  And yes, the union field most certainly feels wrong.